# url rewrite folder .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

here is what I already have in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /go/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /go/index.php [L]
```

What I'm trying to do now is change the name of the folder that a user sees, so:

www.mysite.org/deals/post/

Would be changed to:

www.mysite.org/this/post/

I thought this code would do the trick, but it does absolutely nothing:

```
RewriteRule ^/deals(.*)?$ /this$1 [R]
RewriteRule ^/this(.*)?$ /deals$1 [NC]
```

Is my code wrong?
Are the former rewrite rules conflicting?

Any help is much appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Place this rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` (not in `/go/.htaccess`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^deals/(.*)$ /this/$1 [NC,NE,L,R=302]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure /go/ is the root directory for the site, I tried putting this code in higher directories too and it did nothing. 

When I put it in my current .htaccess it changes the url, but also the displayed page.

I'm trying to have it display
    www.mysite.org/deals/post/
And just have the url show 
    www.mysite.org/this/post/

Comment: If `/go/` is root directory then you don't need `RewriteBase /go/` line.

Comment: Also let me know if this is some CMS that you're using here.

Comment: Yeah I took that out and it still works just fine. And I'm using the GBS (group buying site) theme for wordpress